# How can I add the delete button to my todo list using tailwind css and vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a todo list using tailwind and vanilla js. I have run into a problem where when a task item is added to the list my code is able to render the task text but the edit and delete buttons are missing. I can tell that the funtion is working because in the dev tools I can see that the divs are being created. Thing is there is nothing in them. Could use a hand here?

[image: The Added Task]

[image: The empty divs]

Here are examples of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Include the Tailwind CSS stylesheet -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-neutral-800">
    <div class="font-mono text-slate-400 container mx-auto bg-slate-900 rounded-xl m-12 p-12 task_list_empty">
            <form class="w-auto" id="new-task-form">
                <h1 class="text-3xl text-center">To Do List</h1>
                <div class="m-12">
                    <input type="text" name="task" class="w-full border-2 border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-lg" placeholder="Enter a task" name="new_task_input" id="new_task_input" value="">
                    <button id="new_task_input_button" type="submit" class="bg-slate-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded font-medium">Add</button>
                </div>
                <div class="todo m-12 leading-10">
                    <ul id="todo-list">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="todolist.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
}

@layer components {
    .todo-list-item{
        @apply flex items-center mb-2;
    }
    .todo-list-item__deleteButton{
        @apply bg-rose-900 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded font-medium;
    }
    .todo-list-item__deleteButton:hover{
        @apply bg-rose-800;
    }
    .todo-list-item__editButton{
        @apply bg-teal-900 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded font-medium;
    }
    .todo-list-item__editButton:hover{
        @apply bg-teal-800;
    }

}

@layer utilities {
}
```

```
//Variables
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let newTaskInput = document.getElementById("new_task_input");
let taskform = document.getElementById("new-task-form");
let tasksList = document.getElementById("todo-list");
let deleteBtns = []; // initialize deleteBtns as an empty array

//Add Event Listeners
taskform.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let newTaskInputValue = taskform.elements.new_task_input;
  addTask(newTaskInputValue.value);

  newTaskInputValue.value = "";
  container.classList.remove("task_list_empty");
});

//Add task to list
function addTask(task) {
  const newTaskItem = document.createElement("li");
  newTaskItem.setAttribute("class", "todo-list-item");

  //add the delete button
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "todo-list-item__deleteButton");

  //add the edit button
  const editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.setAttribute("class", "todo-list-item__editButton");

  //add the task text
  const taskText = document.createElement("div");
  taskText.setAttribute("class", "todo-list-item__text");

  //Set the value of the input to the task text
  taskText.innerText = task;

  //append the task text to the list item
  newTaskItem.appendChild(taskText);

  //append the delete button to the li
  newTaskItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

  //append the edit button to the li
  newTaskItem.appendChild(editButton);

  //append the li to the ul
  tasksList.appendChild(newTaskItem);

  //completion funtionality on the delete button
  onTaskCompletion(deleteButton);

  // add the delete button to the array of delete buttons
  deleteBtns.push(deleteButton);
}

//TO remove the task from the list
function onTaskCompletion(deleteButton) {
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    deleteButton.parentElement.remove();
    if (tasksList.children.length === 0) {
      container.classList.add("task_list_empty");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you’re adding any text to your buttons. Try adding some using deleteButton.textContent = “Delete”.